# How much delta-v is expended to get <out of the atmosphere>

Tags: orbital-mechanics

How much delta-v it's spent in getting up to avoid the air drag once in orbit?

Comment: As far I know, the effect of the athmospheric drag causes around 2 km/s delta-V loss on orbital launches.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkeWa.png - Delta-V chart for generalized units. If you want information on a specific craft, numbers will vary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delta-v from atmospheric drag](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/delta-v-from-atmospheric-drag)

Comment: @peterh That's both drag and gravity loss.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Ok, thanks! Then the drag could be calculated with simple mechanics.

Comment: It should depend upon the aerodynamic shape of the rocket and the payload fairing.

Comment: @peterh There's on easy way to figure the drag, although given an actual launch profile you could subtract out the gravity losses and the final energy, what vanished is the drag loss.

Comment: @LorenPechtel What is an interesting question, how do we convert an energy to $\Delta v$. Because the $\frac{\Delta E}{\Delta v}$ is proportional to the current $v$.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Ideally, what we do: 1) elevate the rocket to $\approx$ 300km high 2) accelerate to $\approx 7.8 \frac{km}{s}$ 3) rabble the air around the rocket, overcoming the drag. This 3 sums the total $\Delta v$ of the rocket, which is known data. The energy need of (1) and (2) could be calculated easily by newtonian mechanics, and can be converted to a speed value by $E=\frac{1}mv^2$, using the final mass as $m$. The difference of the two would give the $\Delta v$ loss due to drag.

Comment: @peterh No, that's not what we mean by "gravity loss".  Gravity loss is energy expended simply to keep the rocket from falling back.  For every second of the flight up you must pay local gravity * (1 - velocity/orbital velocity at your altitude.)  Going up and over rather than a proper gravity turn costs me something like 10% in Kerbal Space Program even though it incurs less drag.